# Redirect all lines of code to the same file in a single line

Tags: centos, cron, error-handling, wordpress, hosting-services

I have the following command set used to update all my WordPress sites in my CentOs shared-hosting partition on my hosting provider's platform (via daily cron).

The `wp` commands inside the `pushd-popd` set, are of the [WP-CLI](https://wp-cli.org/) program, which is a Bash extension used for various shell-level actions on WordPress websites.

```
for dir in public_html/*/; do
    if pushd "$dir"; then
        wp plugin update --all
        wp core update
        wp language core update
        wp theme update --all
        popd
    fi
done
```

The directory `public_html` is the directory in which all website directories are located (each website usually has a database and a main file directory).

Given that `public_html` has some directories **which are not** WordPress website directories, than, WP-CLI would return errors regarding them.

To prevent these errors, I assume I could do:

```
for dir in public_html/*/; do
    if pushd "$dir"; then
        wp plugin update --all 2>myErrors.txt
        wp core update 2>myErrors.txt
        wp language core update 2>myErrors.txt
        wp theme update --all 2>myErrors.txt
        popd
    fi
done
```

Instead writing `2>myErrors.txt` four times (or more), is there a way to ensure all errors whatsoever, from every command, will go to the same file, in one line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `> file` operator opens the `file` for writing but truncates it initially. That means that each new `> file` causes the content of the file to be replaced.

If you'd want the `myErrors.txt` to contain the error of all the commands, you'd need either to open that file only once, or use `>` the first time and `>>` the other times (which opens the file in *append* mode).

Here, if you don't mind the `pushd`/`popd` errors to also go to the log file, you can redirect the whole `for` loop:

```
for dir in public_html/*/; do
    if pushd "$dir"; then
            wp plugin update --all
            wp core update
            wp language core update
            wp theme update --all
        popd
    fi
done  2>myErrors.txt
```

Or you could open the log file on a fd above 2, 3 for instance, and use `2>&3` (or `2>&3 3>&-` so as not to pollute commands with fds they don't need) for each command or group of commands you want to redirect to the log file:

```
for dir in public_html/*/; do
    if pushd "$dir"; then
          {
            wp plugin update --all
            wp core update
            wp language core update
            wp theme update --all
          } 2>&3 3>&-
        popd
    fi
done  3>myErrors.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use curly braces to [*group*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Grouping.html) a block and redirect all the output:

```
for dir in public_html/*/; do
    if pushd "$dir"; then
        {
            wp plugin update --all
            wp core update
            wp language core update
            wp theme update --all
        } 2>myErrors.txt
        popd
    fi
done
```